# Redirect my Text View to other layout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent, onclick, xml-layout

How to make my"sodrzina" to be showen on other xml layout.. You can see i have made few tries with setContentView(R.layout.sodrzina); .. with these method i open other layout on click but there is no content. How to show my content there ?

```
         View.OnClickListener 
        getOnClickDoSomething(final Button button)  {
    return new View.OnClickListener() {         
    public void onClick (View v){
        //TextView View = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.viewSodrzina);
        setContentView(R.layout.sodrzina);
         TextView View = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.viewSodrzina);
         String sodrzina="";
    }

    }
        String sodrzina="";

    try{
        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://www.cook-recipes.hostoi.com/jsonscript/sodrzina.php?sodrzina="+(button.getText()).toString().replace(" ","%20"));
        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
        HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
        InputStream webs = entity.getContent();

        try{
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(webs,"iso-8859-1"),8);
            //myListView.setText(reader.readLine());

            int askiChar=0;
            while((askiChar =reader.read())!=-1)
            {
            sodrzina+= ((char)askiChar);
            }
            webs.close();
            reader.close();

        }catch(Exception e){
            Log.e("log_tag","Error converting reslt"+e.toString());
        }

        //TextView prikaziSodrzina = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.viewSodrzina);
        //Toast.makeText(Desert.this,sodrzina, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        //prikaziSodrzina.append(sodrzina);

    //  View.append(sodrzina);



    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Log.e("ERROR","ERROR IN CODE: "+e.toString());
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try [Re-using Layouts with include](http://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/reusing-layouts.html). This will allow you to use same code of layout. How ever the layout will be created twice. Think of it as object inheritance. The alternative is using [addView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.html#addView%28android.view.View,%20int,%20android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams%29) and [removeView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.html#removeView%28android.view.View%29). In this case you will use the same object and it's more efficient speaking in memory use, how ever it's more complicate to create.

Comment: But these content is generated by dynamic buttons i rly need help in code

Comment: i get solved by my self :D i made get layout method and put id on text view from new layout. So everything is ok now . Thanks to all